# Include angular element into expressionengine cms website

Tags: angular7, angular-elements

I exported an angular element into one javascript file so i could include it in a page in my expressionengine cms website but i get the error: SyntaxError: `` literal not terminated before end of script.

The weird part is that i included the script in my localhost:8080/mypage/index.html and works fine!

I would appreciate any help about this, thank you!

Comment: I tried, instead of concatenating 4 scripts generated when running ng build --prod and add it to the index.html file, i added the 4 separated scripts, now i do not get the error but the angular element is not working, nothing is displayed.

Comment: Solved! The issue was that i missed to add <base href="/"> on the header

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The issue was that i missed to add  on the header:

```
<base href="/">
```

Or whatever path you want to place your code in.